# Error in set up procedure of solr with haystack

Tags: django, solr, full-text-search, django-haystack

Tried to install haystack 2.0.0-beta with solr

```
apt-get install solr-jetty
pip install pysolr
pip install django-haystack
```

And edited the following '/etc/default/jetty'

```
NO_START=0            # (line 4)
JETTY_HOST=127.0.0.1  # (line 15)
JETTY_PORT=8983       # (line 18)
```

And started the jetty

```
sudo service jetty start
```

When i tried to access the url

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/
```

got the following error

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Severe errors in solr configuration.

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.PointType'
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory'
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.LatLonType'
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldtype 'location' specified on field *_p
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory'
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.GeoHashField'
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory'
```

How can i fix this issue?Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you configured the solr ? You can look at it's configuration in /path/to/solr/conf/. Try running `sudo service solr start`.